# Python using different Tensorflow version than Conda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda

I installed tensorflow with pip. When I check my tensorflow version inside the conda environment it shows as 2.7.0 as I want it to be. However when  I check it inside python on the same environment, I get 2.6.0. How can I change this so that in both cases I get 2.7.0? I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow inside the environment and upgrading it with pip.

```
(dataset2vec) C:\Users\sozen>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.7.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\sozen\anaconda3\envs\dataset2vec\lib\site-packages
Requires: termcolor, numpy, grpcio, gast, protobuf, absl-py, h5py, typing-extensions, six, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, google-pasta, flatbuffers, tensorboard, keras, wrapt, wheel, keras-preprocessing, libclang, tensorflow-estimator, opt-einsum, astunparse
Required-by: ismlldataset

(dataset2vec) C:\Users\sozen>pip install --upgrade tensorflow
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\sozen\anaconda3\envs\dataset2vec\lib\site-packages (2.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast<0.5.0,>=0.2.1 in c:\users\sozen\anaconda3\envs\dataset2vec\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.4.0)

(dataset2vec) C:\Users\sozen>python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.__version__)"
2.6.0
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the problem was but I created a new environment directly installing tensorflow during creation and inside that environment it still used 2.6.0 with python. Then I forced install 2.7.0 and it magically worked!

Here's a list of the commands I used:

```
conda activate tensorTest
python --version
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.__version__)"
pip install tensorflow
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.__version__)"
>>Still showed 2.6.0
pip install tensorflow==2.7.0
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.__version__)"
>>2.7.0!
```

Comment: Don't mix pip and conda commands! It sounds like you conda isntalled tensorflow when creating the env and then pip installed on top of that

Comment: yes! I didn't know I had to avoid mixing conda and pip commands. Thanks!